# Downloading from ftp with 0's in path

Tags: shell, download

I'm trying to download some data from

ftp://acdisc.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/s4pa/Nimbus4_THIR_Level2/THIRN4L2CH115.001/

and similar locations. I have a shell script (written for me, but I can follow the syntax) which downloads data successfully from

ftp://acdisc.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/s4pa/Nimbus4_THIR_Level2/THIRN4L2CH115.001/1970/

keeping the directory structure the same in the destination directory. However, it breaks down in

ftp://acdisc.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/s4pa/Nimbus4_THIR_Level2/THIRN4L2CH115.001/1971/

because all directories have at least one leading 0. The script that I am currently using attempts to handle this as follows:

```
Low=`echo $initial_dir`
High=`echo $final_dir`

while [ $Low -ne $High ] ;
do
      if [ $Low -lt 100 ]; then
         Low_tmp="0${Low}"  
      fi
      if [ $Low -lt 10 ]; then
         Low_tmp="00${Low}"
      fi
      echo ${dir}/${Low_tmp}
      mkdir -p ${dir}/${Low_tmp}
      cd ${dir}/${Low_tmp}
      wget -c -t inf ftp://acdisc.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/s4pa/Nimbus4_THIR_Level2/THIRN4L2CH115.001/1971/${Low_tmp}/*
      wait
      Low=$(($Low+1))
      echo ${Low}
done
```

Whilst the above creates the directories appropriately in the destination folder, the folders remain empty, suggesting that the issue is on the wget line. Can anybody help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you use the wrong URL?

Try `THIRN4L2CH115.001` instead of `THIRN4L2CH67.001`.

Comment: apologies - that was from another directory within which I am trying the same thing. I changed the url in my script but it still seems to do the same thing: writes the directories but doesn't download anything into them